# Why are some RPG not at all present here?

Tags: discussion

I just came across this SE site and checked to see if the two RP-games I'm familiar with are represented, and sadly they are not.

I'm not greatly surprised that the Swedish DoD clone [Drakar och Demoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakar_och_Demoner) is not here. It's probably a small niche.
But I *am* surprised that something as big as [Warhammer 40000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_40,000_Roleplay) is not here.

Is this site just very young and has very few followers? It [doesn't look like it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games). **Why then?**

Answer (score 11):

In general, the reason for a game not being present is simply that no one has thought to ask a question about that specific game. While we have grown a lot in the past two years, we still don't have a question for every RPG published.

That said, a lot of people have had questions about obscure games answered... Just because you don't see a question for it doesn't mean that no one in the community knows about the game.

Now, you ARE in luck when it comes to Warhammer 40k. While there is no Warhammer 40k tag at the moment, there are several tags related to the specific franchises. Check out:

[dark-heresy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-heresy)

[rogue-trader](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-trader)

[deathwatch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathwatch)

Comment: Yeah, brings up an interesting point about the 40k games.  It would be nice if there was some way to link those tags together.  The other option is tag *all* of the questions with a 40k tag as well.

Comment: @C.Ross likely the best solution is just to put a [tag:wh-40k] on them

Comment: You mean http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k ?

Comment: Is there a maximum character limit on tags? Because I didn't realize until just now what wh20k meant. Very obvious in hindsight I guess.

Comment: @IgneusJotunn 25 characters, I believe. Which means we probably could fit in warhammer-40k. Wh40k is in use because the people who asked those questions used it.